# Getting cookie as a HubL variable

Tags: cookies, twig, hubspot, hubl

In `HubSpot` I'm trying to check if a cookie exists, if it does exist, I'm looking to perform an action through an `if statement`. However, I cannot seem to get the cookie value using `request.cookies` as outlined in [their docs](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/cms/hubl/variables).

Doing the following:

```
{% set cookies = request.cookies %}
{{ cookies }}
```

Returns all the cookies. I'm looking to obtain a single cookie value in a variable.

The cookie I'm trying to obtain in a variable is named `__hssluid`. Since `request.cookies` is of type `dict`, I've tried the following:

```
{% set cookie_name = "__hssluid" %}
{% set result = request.cookies.cookie_name %}
{{ result }}
```

But it doesn't show anything. How can I get a single cookies value using HuBL?

Have also tried the following:

```
{% set cookie_name = "__hssluid" %}
{{ request.cookies[cookie_name] }}
{{ request.cookies.cookie_name }}
{{ request.cookies.__hssluid }}
```

All the above prints nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

To get a value of a cookie with HUBL you just need to do:

```
{{ request.cookies.cookie_name }}
```

without setting the **cookie_name** as a variable

Answer (score 0):

I used this because I ran into the same issue.

```
{% if request.cookies is containing 'cookie_name' %}
    Cookie exists
{% endif %}
```